# How to remove these green arrows in Visual Studio 2010 IDE?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

It seems that I pressed something on the keyboard and these green arrows appeared

[image: Annoying]

they're very annoying. Anyone knows how to get rid of them?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Go to the `Edit` menu, then `Advanced`, and deselect `View White Space`.

Answer (score 37):

<kbd>Ctrl + R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl + W</kbd> toggles the white space display.